# Twig transchoice working for all languages but English

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

The following seems to use the proper translations for comment/comments in languages such as German, French and Portuguese:

```
{% transchoice newsItem.commentCount from 'frontpage' %}news_comments{% endtranschoice %}
```

For English, instead of selecting one from comment|comments, it shows "1 comment|comments" if newsItem.commentCount == 1. If it is more than 1, it shows only "comments" properly.

Anyone have an idea what could be happening?

EDIT: English translations file:

```
"slug","source","translation","context"
"comment","comment|comments","comment|comments",""
```

Other languages follow same structure.

Comment: please post the relevant translations file also

Comment: Added translations file structure